# Python sort list of ctype structure

Tags: python, sorting, ctypes

I have a ctype structure as bellow:

```
class BOX(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_float),
                ("y", c_float),
                ("w", c_float),
                ("h", c_float)]

class DETECTION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cl", c_int),
                ("bbox", BOX),
                ("prob", c_float)]
```

and ML model passing detection result via share libs

```
lib = CDLL('./libdetector.so', RTLD_GLOBAL)
detect          = lib.detect
detect.argtypes = [...]
detect.restype  = POINTER(DETECTION)

dets = detect(...)
```

My code work fine, I checked the result and it is correct. But I want to sort detection by its confidence score, so I use this line:

```
_dets = sorted(dets, key=lambda det: det.prob, reverse=True)
```

In this step, my computer's memory keep going and when it is full, only "Killed" message was printed to my console. So, does python `sorted` not work with a list of ctype structure? I can simply use `for loop` to sort, but everyone want to keep code clean and beauty, don't we? :3

Comment: So, if it is a `POINTER(DETECTION)` result, it *is not a list*. But using `sorted` **creates** a list, what's more, is composed of `ctypes.c_float` objects, which require *128 bytes* per instance at the python level (the enitre underlying struct will be less than half of that), plus don't forget the 8 bytes for the pointer. So if that underlying array is already substantially large, this could balloon your memory requirements... Python is a huge memory hog compared to C. Use `numpy` if you want to efficiently work with array of structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dets` is an pointer to a detection structure, but has no associated size.  When passed to `sorted()` Python will start iterating the pointer forever adding objects to the list it wants to sort, or even crashing if it accesses uncommitted memory.

Example:

```py
from ctypes import *

class BOX(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_float),
                ("y", c_float),
                ("w", c_float),
                ("h", c_float)]

class DETECTION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cl", c_int),
                ("bbox", BOX),
                ("prob", c_float)]

    def __init__(self,prob):  # Add some data to differentiate objects
        self.prob = prob

    def __repr__(self):       # Add a display representation
        return f'D(prob={self.prob})'

# Create a ctypes array of three DETECTION objects
a = (DETECTION * 3)(DETECTION(1.25), DETECTION(3.5), DETECTION(2.25))

# Create a pointer to the first element of the array
# simulating OP's return value from ctypes.
dets = cast(byref(a),POINTER(DETECTION))

print(dets)
print(dets[0])
print(dets[2])
_dets = sorted(dets, key=lambda det: det.prob, reverse=True) # HANGS
print(_dets)
```

Output:

```py
<__main__.LP_DETECTION object at 0x000002032B7FDC40>
D(prob=1.25)
D(prob=2.25)
# On my system hangs here like OP described.
```

The fix is you need to know the size of the returned array, and to slice the returned pointer to that known size.  The array size in this case was three:

```py
_dets = sorted(dets[:3], key=lambda det: det.prob, reverse=True)
```

Output:

```py
<__main__.LP_DETECTION object at 0x000001F31763DC40>
D(prob=1.25)
D(prob=2.25)
[D(prob=3.5), D(prob=2.25), D(prob=1.25)]
```

Comment: Thank, you save my day. To apply ur method, I only need to provide one more variable that get length of ```dets```, and it's easy for me than juanpa's method.

Answer (score 1):

So, if it is a `POINTER(DETECTION)` result, it *is not a list*. But using `sorted` **creates** a list, what's more, is composed of `ctypes.c_float` objects, which require *128 bytes* per instance, plus don't forget the 8 bytes for the pointer. So if that underlying array is already substantially large, this could balloon your memory requirements...

```
import numpy.ctypeslib

arr = numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(dect, shape=(n,))
arr.sort(order='prob')
```

where `n` has to be the size of the resulting array.

Note, that the resulting numpy structured array object *is simply a wrapper around the underlying buffer*. It requires a small, constant amount of auxiliary space -- although watch out, some `numpy` functions/methods might copy, but it won't be as bad as creating a list of `ctypes` objects!